# Adding a second argument to a function

Tags: swift

How do I add and use a second argument to a function in swift that uses " _ " ? For example in this func:

```
func save(completion: (_ finished: Bool) -> ()) {
```

And when I use it is like this:

```
  self.save { (complete) in
        if complete {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

But I want to add another argument, a UIColor. Everytime I do it I get errors because I'm not using the arguments correct. How do I add a UIColor in my func? I did it like this

```
func save(color: UIColor,completion: (_ finished: Bool) -> ()) {
```

and when I used :

```
 self.save(color: green, { (complete) in
    if complete {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

but I get an error about the Bool type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write

```
self.save(color: green) { complete in // the parentheses are not needed
    if complete {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling a function with completion, the easiest way that you won't have mistakes while calling the function, click enter when you're on the "blue square" of the argument. It will edit all of the function as it should look like.